# Computational complexity of expanding brackets with variables $x_i \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Consider integer coefficient polynomials in $x_i \in \{0,1\}$

E.g. $(x_1+1)(x_1x_2+x_2+1) \tag{1}$

Since $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ we have that ${x_i}^p=x_i$, then $(1)$ expands to

$$3x_1x_2 + x_1 + x_2 +1 $$

Is there a name for this type of algebra? It reminds me of $\mathbb{F}_2$ but with standard integer coefficients.

Given that the largest $i$ is $n$, the maximum number of terms in the expansion is $2^{n}$.

Does this mean there is a $O(n)$ algorithm for expanding the brackets? What if we were to product more of these polynomials together. How does the computational complexity change?

Thanks in advance for any help / advice. Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a name for this type of algebra?

If each $x_i$ is either zero or one then we have $x_i(x_i - 1) = 0$, so I guess you can work over the ring

$$R := \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\left(x_1^2 - x_1,\;  \ldots, \; x_n^2 - x_n\right)$$

I don't know if there's a specific name for this ring, but an element such that $x^2 = x$ is called an *idempotent*.

> Given that the largest $i$ is $n$, the maximum number of terms in the expansion is $2^n$.  Does this mean there is a $O(n)$ algorithm for expanding the brackets?

No.  For instance, assume we're computing a product $f g$ where $f$ is some general element of $R$ and $g = 1$.  Then multiplying $f$ and $g$ just amounts to copying $f$, but copying $f$ requires $O(2^n)$ time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does the computational complexity change at all if we product more polynomials together?

Comment: I don't think there's an advantage to complexity here, unless you count something like this: if we want to multiply $(a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_r x^r)(b_0 + b_1x + \ldots + b_s x^s)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then we need to look at the terms pairwise, whereas over $R$ we can reduce the factors to $(a_0 + A x)(b_0 + B x)$.  So we reduce from $O(r s)$ to $O(r +s)$.

Comment: If the terms are already written in a form where no $x_i$ appears to a power higher than 1 then I don't think that working over R is any better than working over $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$, though I haven't proven this.